# Why aren't Arguments after the first two in my Union (Arg1, Arg2...) expressed in my Values?

Tags: excel, vba

Without going into depth on my project, I'm trying to Match values between workbook sheets and for each sheet I want to create a Union of 3 columns (in a row) to Match on, but when I setup the Union to obtain the values for matching I only see the first two Arguments of my Union being produced when calling for Values.

Below is the code and an image of my Locals...

```
Sub TestUnion()

    Dim Filename2 As Variant: Filename2 = Worksheets("SOURCES").Range("A2") & ".xlsx"
    Dim WB2 As Workbook: Set WB2 = Workbooks(Filename2)

    Dim SourceRngB, SourceRngC, SourceRngF, SourceRng As Range
    Set SourceRngB = WB2.Worksheets("LIVE KEYS").Range("$B$27")
    Set SourceRngC = WB2.Worksheets("LIVE KEYS").Range("$C$27")
    Set SourceRngF = WB2.Worksheets("LIVE KEYS").Range("$F$27")
    Set SourceRng = Union(SourceRngB, SourceRngC, SourceRngF)

    Dim SourceVal As Variant: SourceVal = SourceRng.Value

End Sub
```

[image]

I expect all 3 range values to be expressed in the Locals.

Btw, the "27" you see in the code will ultimately be a variable that changes within a loop ("$B$" & x) starting from 2 to y (number of rows) so I can compare 3 cells (Bx,Cx,Fx) on each row of my "LIVE" sheet with other "TEST" sheets and paste the match into a Results sheet. The code will be run from the Results sheet.

Comment: It is only loading the first `Area` of the `Range`  You will need to iterate the `Area`s and load the array.  You cannot mass load and array from a disjointed range.

Comment: Make a loop `For Each rngArea In SourceRng.Areas`

Comment: Scott & Mathieu, I'm not sure how this looks in code.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Is this what you mean? https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008703_Stepping_Through_a_Non-Contiguous_Range_of_Cells.html